# Python process tracklist, get cumulative timestamp of each track

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, datetime, formatting

The code below parses a tracklist (sample input below) and generates a six-member tuple, including cumulative timestamps in `mm:ss`. (sample output at bottom).

- couldn't easily see how to rewrite it from a for-loop to a generator `get_track_with_cumulative_timestamp(itt)`
- I think we don't need a custom object, i.e. avoid [this approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166158/split-mp3-of-album-into-individual-tracks)
- generator will need to internally store state `(tmm, tss)` being the end-time of each song. So we yield each result with the start-time of each song; incrementing the time-arithmetic comes after that.
- are there better idioms for the (mm,ss) modulo-60 counters? `decimal.Decimal` seems overkill. I suppose we could always pull a trick internally using one float to represent both (mm,ss)

Current not-so-great procedural code:

```
tracklist = """
1. Waiting For A Miracle 5:02
2. Bedroom Eyes 5:01
3. In Over My Head 4:31
4. Higher Ground / Written-By – S. Wonder* 3:38
5. Hot Blood 4:15
6. Running Away 4:28
7. I've Had Enough 3:47
8. Blacklisted / Guitar [Other] – Jonny Fean* 4:11
9. Last Thing At Night 2:49"""

tracklist = [t for t in tracklist.split('\n') if t]

import re

pat = re.compile(r'(?P<no>[0-9]+)\. (?P<name>.*) (?P<mm>[0-9]+):(?P<ss>[0-9]+)')

(tmm,tss) = (0,0)
result = []

for t in tracklist:
    m = pat.match(t)
    #print(m.groups())
    lmm, lss = int(m['mm']), int(m['ss'])

    result.append((int(m['no']), tmm, tss, lmm, lss, m['name']))
    #yield (int(m['no']), tmm, tss, lmm, lss, m['name']))

    tss += lss
    tmm += lmm
    if tss >= 60:
        tmm += 1
        tss -= 60

# Output looks like this:
for _ in result: print('{} | {:02d}:{:02d} | {}:{:02d} | {}'.format(*_))
```

```
1 | 00:00 | 5:02 | Waiting For A Miracle
2 | 05:02 | 5:01 | Bedroom Eyes
3 | 10:03 | 4:31 | In Over My Head
4 | 14:34 | 3:38 | Higher Ground / Written-By – S. Wonder*
5 | 18:12 | 4:15 | Hot Blood
6 | 22:27 | 4:28 | Running Away
7 | 26:55 | 3:47 | I've Had Enough
8 | 30:42 | 4:11 | Blacklisted / Guitar [Other] – Jonny Fean*
9 | 34:53 | 2:49 | Last Thing At Night
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question with modified code. Once you've gathered sufficient feedback from this question, CRSE policy is that you open a new question.

Comment: @Reinderien: I didn't gather 'sufficient feedback'; your answer did not actually address how to do better idiom for the (mm,ss) modulo-60 counter for this use-case. We're not talking about generalized timedeltas of anything from milliseconds to years.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that my answer was conclusive... I'm suggesting that you leave this open until you're satisfied with my (or someone else's) feedback. Patience.

Comment: I've rolled this back per https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c

Comment: @Reinderien: ok I wasn't aware of the no-code-revisions policy. And yes you're right about `datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Implicit tuples

```
(tmm,tss) = (0,0)
```

This shouldn't need any parens.

### Generator

> couldn't easily see how to rewrite it from a for-loop to a generator

It actually is quite easy. Make your code into a function, delete `result`, and replace `result.append` with `yield`.

### Time spans

> are there better idioms for the (mm,ss) modulo-60 counters?

[Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)!

### Custom objects

> I think we don't need a custom object

Named tuples take one line to declare, and suck less than unstructured data. So do that, at least.

### Underscores

I just noticed that you're looping with an underscore as your loop variable. By convention this means "I'm not going to use this value"... but then you used it anyway. Give this variable a meaningful name.

### Example

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import timedelta

TRACK_PAT = re.compile(r'(?P<no>[0-9]+)\. (?P<name>.*) (?P<mm>[0-9]+):(?P<ss>[0-9]+)$', re.M)
Track = namedtuple('Track', ('number', 'time', 'length', 'name'))


def parse_track(body):
    t_total = timedelta()
    for match in TRACK_PAT.finditer(body):
        length = timedelta(minutes=int(match['mm']), seconds=int(match['ss']))
        yield Track(int(match['no']), t_total, length, match['name'])
        t_total += length


for track in parse_track(
"""
1. Waiting For A Miracle 5:02
2. Bedroom Eyes 5:01
3. In Over My Head 4:31
4. Higher Ground / Written-By – S. Wonder* 3:38
5. Hot Blood 4:15
6. Running Away 4:28
7. I've Had Enough 3:47
8. Blacklisted / Guitar [Other] – Jonny Fean* 4:11
9. Last Thing At Night 2:49"""
):
    print(f'{track.number} | {track.time} | {track.length} | {track.name}')
```

Comment: 1) Yes I know parens are not needed around implicit tuples, I wanted to be explicit that it's an mm:ss counter 2) Done 3) Time spans with `datetime.timedelta` seem to be overkill *for this use-case* like I said: can you show equivalent code that is <=8 lines long? I doubt it.

Comment: Given that your code is currently about 33 lines long, 8 lines seems like an unrealistic request. Regardless, I'll post example code.

Comment: You're missing my point that `datetime.timedelta` is not good for this particular use-case and will be lomger, more clunky and less readable than the current.

Comment: You asked for a better idiom. Doing one's own time math is a foul code smell. If you don't like it, don't listen to me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm aware that doing one's own time math is generally a bad code smell, that's precisely one of the two reasons I posted this question in the first place. However I did listen to your comments and you haven't shown any better code idiom for this use-case. `datetime.timedelta` is terrible overkill.

Comment: Btw my code clearly isn't 33 lines long. The generator body is only 10 lines long. That's my point to you: it's hard to see how anyone can show shorter code than the (admittedly distasteful) manual modulo-60 mm,ss counter tuple. (Without hacking into a single float, which is even more distasteful)

Comment: Ok thanks you were right and I was wrong, that is much more compact and elegant. Mind you the `datetime.timedelta` doc doesn't showcase that. As to the need for an object/ namedtuple Track, really we just want some sort of object or tuple which can take a custom `__str__()` method.

Comment: Accepted. Any thoughts on how to improve the `datetime.timedelta` doc? It is all syntax and no examples. I've used it for 10 years and never realized it could do that.

Comment: Improve the documentation? How? It seems quite clear to me. It spells out which kwargs are accepted by the constructor.

Comment: Reinderien: there's zero documentation to say that `'{}'.format(timedelta(month=6, minutes=4, seconds=32))` magically works **without any strftime format string and gives a smart format, dropping unneeded leading zero fields week, day**. Thus: `'0:04:32'`. Yet `'{}'.format(timedelta(weeks=6, minutes=4, seconds=32))` gives `'42 days, 0:04:32'`. No documentation of that smart-formatting behavior in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) or `help(datetime)`. I would have expected unwanted leading and trailing junk like `(0 days, ..., 0 milliseconds)`

Comment: That's also documented quite clearly. `Returns a string in the form [D day[s], ][H]H:MM:SS[.UUUUUU], where D is negative for negative t.` Those square brackets are Backus-Naur format, and mean that the days, leading hour digits and microseconds are optional.

Comment: No it's not and I just stated why, and I've been using it for 10+ years. The doc implies that `'{}'.format(timedelta(month=6, minutes=4, seconds=32))` would render as `(0 days, ..., 0 milliseconds)` and nowhere does it say that unused leading or trailing zero fields get dropped. Yes we know what Backus-Naur format is, but the dropping is not being communicated. Look, the doc is deficient for both the constructor, `__str__` and other formatting methods in not explicitly saying "if a timedelta only has min and sec, that is all that will get shown, with one single leading zero hour digit"....

Comment: ...and here's a [blatant counterexample from the 2.6 doc showing that you can and do get unwanted junk 'days' values](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/datetime.html) : Note that normalization of negative values may be surprising at first. For example: `timedelta(microseconds=-1)` gives `(d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)` = `(-1, 86399, 999999)`

Answer (score 3):

This part is not that compact in terms of code lines, which you seek to decrease:

> ```
> tss += lss
> tmm += lmm
> if tss >= 60:
>     tmm += 1
>     tss -= 60
> ```

One solution is to keep track of `t` (total seconds) instead of `tss` and `tmm`.

```
t = 0
result = []

for t in tracklist:
    m = pat.match(t)
    lmm, lss = int(m['mm']), int(m['ss'])

    result.append((int(m['no']), t // 60, t % 60, lmm, lss, m['name']))

    t += 60 * lmm + lss
```

Comment: Also a good approach (to the arithmetic). Yes I get that it can equally be done in a generator.

Comment: it can easily be transformed using a generator if you want. My point was only about that modulo logic :)

Answer (score 1):

Here was my updated v0.02 written as a generator. (Can combine with either Reinderien's `datetime.timedelta` aproach or dfhwze's modulo code)

```
import re

#tracklist = """... as defined above ..."""
tracklist = iter(t for t in tracklist.split('\n') if t)

pat = re.compile(r'(?P<no>[0-9]+)\. (?P<name>.*) (?P<mm>[0-9]+):(?P<ss>[0-9]+)')

def gen_cumulative_timestamp(itracklist):
    tmm, tss = 0, 0

    for t in itracklist:
        m = pat.match(t)
        lmm, lss = int(m['mm']), int(m['ss'])

        yield ( int(m['no']),  tmm, tss, lmm, lss, m['name'] )

        tss += lss
        tmm += lmm
        if tss >= 60:
            tmm += 1
            tss -= 60

for t in gen_cumulative_timestamp(tracklist):
    # Ideally should have a custom object/NamedTuple which has a custom __str__() method
    print('{} | {:02d}:{:02d} | {}:{:02d} | {}'.format(*t))
```